# SQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to save Entity with Composite Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

these are my classes

UserActivity

```
@Entity
@Data
@IdClass(UserActivityId.class)
public class UserActivity {

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Stream stream;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "stream_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long streamId;

    @Id
    private String userIp;

    //...8 more fields

}
```

UserActivityId

```
@Data
public class UserActivityId implements Serializable {
    private Long userId;
    private Long streamId;
    private String userIp;

    //constructors
}
```

Stream

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Stream {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stream")
    private List<UserActivity> UserActivities = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

User

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected long id;
}
```

UserActivityRepository

```
public interface UserActivityRepository extends JpaRepository<UserActivity, UserActivityId>  
}
```

but when i try to save an entity like this :

```
var stream = streamRepository.findById(activity.getStreamId);
var user = userRespository.findById(activity.getUserId);
activity.setStream(stream);
activity.setUser(user);
userActivityRepository.save(activity);
```

i get and exception like this:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1058) Could not set parameter at position 12 (values was 1)
Query - conn:1058(M)  - "insert into user_activity (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, user_id, stream_id, user_ip) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

which is strange because i only have 11 fields and hibernate is trying to set the 12th parameter
i tried recreating the database and the problem persisted, but when i remove the composite key it works

Comment: Sometimes 3rd party software causes more grief than benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally out found what the problem was,i had to place `@id` above the relationship references (Stream, User) instead of their foreign keys, also i needed to add `@MapsId` to them

```
 @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    
    @Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @MapsId
    private Stream stream;

    
    @Column(name = "stream_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long streamId;

    @Id
    private String userIp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining `insertable=false, updatable=false` is useful when you need to map a field more than once in an entity through a `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne` mapping.

I think to fix this issue you need to remove `insertable=false, updatable=false` from the `Column` annotation.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_Relationships

Comment: no i don't think that's the problem, also the `insertable` and `updatable` are necessary because i need both the relation object (stream) and the foreign key (stream_id)